# Are there 'headshot' or 'limb' damage, and other specific body part hit effects in Alan Wake?

Tags: alan-wake

I'd like to know if there are any differences in damage and other effects (like limping) if I aim for the head, limbs or other body parts of enemies, or does it not matter which body part got hit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There does not appear to be any effect to shooting a particular part of an enemy's body. Most notably, I've landed 4 square headshots in a row on a bulky Taken, and it still took 6 revolver shots to kill on medium difficulty.