# What can I do if I run out of ammo?

Tags: alan-wake

During the second chapter of *Alan Wake* I ran into a situation where I was running low on ammo. Luckily, I managed to kill the last enemy with my last bullet and the episode ended shortly afterwards, but I was wondering what would've been my options if I did, in fact, run out of ammo and still had to face enemies.

As far as I could tell, the only way to defeat enemies is either by shooting them or getting to a safe spot, but is there always a safe spot to escape to? Are there alternative "ammo-independent" methods of killing enemies which can be used in case I run out of ammo? Could I possibly get stuck on the same checkpoint without enough ammo, forcing me to restart the whole chapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there is always a safe spot to escape to, eventually, there are times where reaching it without the ability to fire your weapon would prove very difficult (I'm thinking of a certain ambush on a bridge, for example). 
That being said, if you're good enough at dodging, then you are theoretically invincible, but dodging multiple enemies in often confined spaces (waiting for some gate to open, for example) is most likely to fail. While it's true that boosting your flashlight could also serve to slow down enemies and give you room to breathe, the amount of enemies that are after you, at times, can make this benefit very negligible.

While there are indirect ways of killing enemies, these are only available in specific places and are not something you can rely on (there are some enemies that can be taken out with just the flashlight, but they are not the majority).

To sum it up, I firmly believe that you can find yourself in a situation where you are effectively stuck due to a lack of ammunition.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you had to just be more efficient with shots- to the head see,ed to wok better. I found a good tactic was to avoid as many conflicts as possible and simply dash/dodge past enemies in a bid to reach the safe spot

I had to play some chapters again for some achievements and I was surprised at how much ammo I was able to conserve simply by dashing ahead.

Bear in mind that enemies usually slow down when you shine the torch at them, which is also helpful when running ahead.

Also, only fire when you are sure your shot will hit. Holding the L trigger gently will allow you to aim without boosting your flashlight which can also help.

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what to do if the player has *already* run out of ammo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I doubt the "aim for the head parts though", from personal experience, and [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53858/are-there-headshot-or-limb-damage-and-other-specific-body-part-hit-effects?rq=1)

Comment: If you're out of ammo, you're screwed- leg it.